# How important is future big purchases (house) when setting up guaranteed investment accounts?

Tags: investing, canada, bank-account, first-time-home-buyer, savings-account

I moved out of my parents's house a couple weeks ago. I moved into an apartment in a big city and I am not sure yet if I will like it here or not.   I have no idea when I'll switch to a house and if it will be around the same place.

For now, my apartment has a one year contract so I'm here for at least a year.

I've been looking to start investments, saving up for a house. I started a retirement fund.

(I don't know if that's the right word, but what I refer to as "guaranteed investment" is my crude translation of a french word for an account that gives you a higher interest rate in exchange for locking your funds away for a certain time. The longer you lock it, the higher the interest rate when the time is up)

I'm very interested in this kind of account because getting 2.5-3.5% interest is much better than the usual 1.25% I get for normal accounts. I'm not sure how liberal I should be with locking away funds if I don't know when I'll need to take out as much money as possible for a down payment on a house.

So the question is: How comfortable should I be with investing money like this? If I decide to buy the house 1 year before the term is up, how much money will I lose in interest by having a smaller down payment because of that? Would it still be worth it?

Comment: I think that you answered your question when you wrote "I'm not sure how liberal I should be with locking away funds if I don't know when I'll need to take out as much money as possible for a down payment on a house."  If you think that you may need the money then it's not a good idea to lock up the money if penalties will be incurred to access your money before the full term is reached.

Comment: @BobBaerker I know that the best situation is buying a house at a moment when all my funds are available. The question is, is it more profitable for me to take advantage of those interest rates, even if that ends up reducing my down payment if I end up buying before the term is up, or is it more profitable to make 100% sure i get the maximum down payment, even if that means not taking advantage of higher interest rates until then (and it might be several years from now)

Comment: I would urge you to go absolutely-all-out to secure a piece of real estate.  The tiny number 1%, 3% are completely dwarfed by the advantages of securing your first flat or house.  I would live as if your hair is on fire, until you secure that first mortgage.  It's just not worth "fussing" about the distraction of 1% here or there - keep it liquid as if you are utterly focussed on the flat!  GOOD LUCK!!

Comment: Are you in France? Investment vehicles vary by country. For example, in the US we have CD's which are as you describe, but typically the funds are not truly locked away, they can be withdrawn early for a penalty (several months of interest), making them quite flexible.

Comment: @HartCO Canada, if that makes a difference

Comment: Is it a Guaranteed Investment Certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one man's opinion,

Securing that first mortgage is also a mental-psychological battle.

The fact is the tiny 1% here or there differences under discussion **will be dwarfed** on all fronts by the economics of the (wonderful) moment of securing that first mortgage.

I suggest keep your financial life **totally focussed** on that coming moment when you secure your first flat or house...

Forget the issue of the tiney 1-2% differences and **stay liquid**, with a total focus for you mentally on securing that first mortgage.

Bon chance!

---

Most importantly, if your aim is to kick around the world and live/work in sundry places, this is the best thing you can do.

OP is in City/Country X presntly. He buys the flat. He decides to go gallavanting around the world and goes off to live in Osaka or Sydney or LA for a year or five. He simply rents out out flat in city X, maintaining ownership of it.

Sure, there may be some tiny random expenses now and again in doing this.  But so what: "kicking around the world" involves constant tiny expenses. (Moving things, re-buying cutlery constantly, oddball medical expenses, sudden flights needed, and so on. Once in a blue moon if you have a maintenance cost or the like - believe me, it is no different from the other endless costs you will have in "living globally".)

With your "handy anchor" back in X, you will be constantly building your overall ultimate wealth, even as you piss about on the world stage.  And it is spectacularly advantageous entrée to be able to say "sure I'm a home owner" when you are mucking about globally.

Comment: I could go and buy a house right now with the money I have saved and my current income. I have tried it just for fun, and most banks pre-approve me for a large enough amount to buy a decent house right now. The thing is, I don't want a house right now, since I'm still unsure if I want to live my life in my current city.

Comment: Howdy @KaitoKid - I like your style.   I will offer you a critical gem, ***you have MORE, not less, freedom once you secure that first piece of real estate.***  it is much, much easier to bounce around the world working, once you have secured that first flat or house.  Good luck to you!

Comment: @Fattie I love your enthusiasm for property ownership, but if there's a high probability that you'd move in the next 2 years, then buying is likely not worthwhile. You risk losing money/being stuck with a house you can't sell for what you paid if the housing market dips. To break even the property would have to appreciate enough to cover realtor fees, in many markets that wouldn't happen in 2-years.

Comment: I disagree, @HartCO , based on a lifetime of "bumming around the world".  OP is in City/Country X.  He buys the flat.   He decides to go gallavanting around the world and goes off to live in Japan for a year or five.  He simply rents out out flat in city X, maintaining ownership of it.

Comment: @Fattie Not all markets are good rental markets, and you have to be in a position to cover vacancies and any major repairs. Not to mention limitations imposed by mortgages that don't allow renting within first 'x' years. It might work out great, but a much better bet is buying somewhere that you are content to be for a few years at least. It's not a sure thing, is my point, and it becomes less of a sure thing the shorter the time line.

Comment: Of course I fully understand your points, @HartCO  But *"Not all markets are good rental markets"* ....... you can give that caveat to - literally anything in life.  (1) Any investment, whatsoever, of any genre whatsoever (2) Any conceivable career choice by the OP  (2) Any marriage partner (far and away the main deciding factor in financial/life success)  (3) Any chosen educational career whatsoever.   My point is (A) sure there may be the occasional cost, *and this is trivialized by the endless, relentless cost you will find in "living globally"*, and (B) overall there are huge advantages

Comment: Consider: the bald statement "you should save for retirement" is incredibly true. I'd say, you probably agree. Now, say you said "you should save for retirement". Of course, I could reply "Oh, many such investments often plummet in many cases. Here are some examples. .. Etc". That's quite true but the bald statement "you should save for retirement" remains incredibly true. OP will be overwhelmingly aided in his course if he buys a flat "instantly". {note that! merely! the rental$ he will save in the next few months while mucking about **will alone offset a year of world dalliance**}

Comment: That's how I see it !

Comment: Buying ASAP and banking on rental income while living elsewhere is far riskier than you make it sound. Rental income is not guaranteed, cost of home ownership can be very high, renting from a distance is even costlier, and it may not be plausible to rent depending on mortgage options. I agree with the sentiment about not fussing much over a percentage of interest in the short-term, but that unbridled optimism about home ownership needs to be tempered. That's how I see it... ;)

Comment: *"banking on rental income while living elsewhere is far riskier than you make it sound"*  I really understand what you mean.  I would say in reasonable situations (reasonably major world cities, tech centers, where OP probably has his first job under discussion) it's a very moderate risk.  Again, if you happen to suffer a say $10,000 pain due to a rental loss or maintenance item, that is not a big deal compared to the endless cost of "mucking around living in different parts of the world."  With huge advantages.

Comment: @Fattie I think your views are colored too much by where you live. For example, in the Netherlands, it's still common to get mortgages without a down payment and banks typically do not allow you to rent a house out with a LTV over 50% or so due to the high degree of tenant rights. If you were to buy there and move to somewhere like the US where a down payment of 20% is strongly advised or required, then keeping the property and buying again soon is just not possible.

Comment: I know what you mean @eric but (A) op is in Canada (B) I'm pretty familiar w/ houses in US, a number of countries on the continent, UK, HK, Aus. ("I've thrown away money in all of them!"  :) ) and mostly **life is very short**, you have to grab it by the nuts as Shakespeare said, or take it on the flood tide.  Sure, there could be a "horrible chain" of bad events that leads to the utterly worst case where .......... he owns a house!  So he's adventuring in Tokyo or San Francisco or something and for one "whole year" he has to pay the whole thing while sharing and working at google - go for it!

Answer (score 1):

The benefits and drawbacks of locking up savings seem marginal, compared to the direct impact of the decision whether and when to buy a house. I would come down slightly on the side of maintaining liquidity.

First, the comparison of current shorter-term versus longer-term deposit rates is not exactly what it seems. If you keep your savings liquid, the 1.25% rate will not remain the same forever. Arguably it is more likely to go up than down. The long-term deposits would not be paying what they are, if rates were expected to decline. So some of the difference will probably be recouped.

Second, the option to make a larger down payment could help you avoid the cost of private mortgage insurance (PMI) or equivalent. (If you have good credit, the amount of your down payment above say 5% probably won't have a strong effect on your interest rate, though.)

With liquidity you also would have the option, of course, to make a smaller down payment if that is best at the time (e.g., to retain savings for other expenses or for retirement).